# How to Uninstalling MariaDB and mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Even after doing the below steps in my Mac, I am unable to uninstall Mysql and Maria dB.
Could someone please check the below and help.

"Open a terminal window

Use mysqldump to backup your databases to text files!

Stop the database server

sudo rm /usr/local/mysql

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*

sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM

sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*

edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-

rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*

sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*

sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*

sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO.

Comment: Move to dba.stackexchange.com